# Maven Thrift repository

Tags: maven, thrift

Does anyone know if the Thrift libraries are in any Maven repository?

Comment: Yes the artifacts are available in releases > 0.6.1. The official version can be found at repository.apache.org. Snapshots and release candidates can be found off my apache homepage. Thanks for using Thrift

Answer (score 9):

0.6.1 artifacts now available from main apache repo (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-363

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the Thrift libraries are (next time, maybe add a link) but according to [Maven Browser](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/), there is a [thrift artifact](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifact-details.html?groupId=com.facebook&artifactId=thrift&version=1.0&tab=FILES#tabs) in the [scala-tools repository](http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/):

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>scala-tools</id>
    <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Update:** I can't say much about the version (and the content) hosted in the scala-tools repository but this is very likely an artifact made available by the scala folks for their own needs. Actually, the Apache Thrift project is using Ivy and publishing the java library to a maven repository (it will be the [Apache snapshots repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/), see [THRIFT-363](https://cwiki.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-363)) is something on which they didn't work until recently. But the issue is closed now and my understanding is that they will publish an artifact with the next release.

Comment: http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/download/ weird that in the repo it says version 1.0, but on the web page its only 0.2.0

Comment: I think latest version at this point is 0.5.0, as per http://thrift.apache.org/download/.

Comment: ... or, as of yesterday, it's 0.6.0. And still not in Maven (how freaking hard is it to do that? seriously)

Answer (score 0):

As of now there are not any available, you will have to include the jar in your local repository.

You can set up something like Artefactory, a local repository and add the libthrift.jar there.

Comment: That is another frustrating thing about thrift jars, not containing version number. Hard to know which version is even included by 3rd party libs, frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.thrift/libthrift

You can search Maven repository from there.